# How to implement multiple different serializers for same model using ActiveModel::Serializers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, rest, activemodel

Let's say you're implementing a REST API in Rails.  When serving a collection, you might want to only include a few attributes:

```
/people
```

But when serving a single resource, you want to include all the attributes:

```
/people/1
```

I don't see how to do that using ActiveModel::Serializers, since the examples all use the pattern of defining one serializer per model (with a standard naming convention) and having AMS automatically use the right one in the controller when you do:

```
render json: @people
```

or:

```
render json: @person
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid mixing view concerns into your models (via serialized variations), use the view to render your JSON for each action, much like we do for HTML.

[jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) & [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) both fill this data templating need quite nicely.

**Update 2013-12-16**: The [ActiveModelSerializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) library does support defining multiple serializers for one model, as @phaedryx answered later, by using [custom serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#3-subclass-the-serializer-and-specify-using-it).

Comment: So, what you're saying is that AMS doesn't yet have the flexibility in it's current design to satisfy this common use case of differently serializing for different API responses?  Because that's how it feels, but I didn't want to assume the problem wasn't simply my own ignorance, especially since AMS is being considered for Rails4 core as "the way"...

Comment: jbuilder was created by DHH specifically to address this problem in Rails. Creating variations via ActiveModel::Serializers will end up putting public-API (view) concerns in your controllers &/or models.

Comment: Ok. Obviously I need to look at jbuilder and then decide how to proceed, but it was a good answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 130):

You *can* have multiple serializers for the same model, e.g.

```
class SimplePersonSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name
end
```

and

```
class CompletePersonSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :phone, :email
end
```

simple info for people in one controller:

```
render json: @people, each_serializer: SimplePersonSerializer
```

complete info for people in another:

```
render json: @people, each_serializer: CompletePersonSerializer
```

simple info for a single person:

```
render json: @person, serializer: SimplePersonSerializer
```

complete info for a single person:

```
render json: @person, serializer: CompletePersonSerializer
```

Comment: How can I have the key as `person: {}` not `complete_person: {}`?

Comment: @chopper yes. you just need to append `root: :person`. Here is a full example `render json: @person, serializer: CompletePersonSerializer, root: :person`

Comment: You can subclass `class CompletePersonSerializer < SimplePersonSerializer` and include just the new attributes

Comment: @SeifSallam You can add the `root: person` to the serializer class it self. It doesn't need be specified everywhere you call `render json`

Comment: Phaedryx and @Swards you guys are my heroes!

Comment: Is there any way to specify this for each action automatically at the controller level?

Comment: it would be very handy to change this to the answer.

Answer (score 11):

```
class CompletePersonSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  root :person
  attributes :id, :name, :phone, :email
end
```

or

```
render json: @people, each_serializer: CompletePersonSerializer, root: :person
```

Comment: as of today, `root :person` raises an error. `each_serializer: CompletePersonSerializer` is sufficient

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what @phaedryx said, what I do for this is call a method that returns the correct serializer... for your question, I'd use:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

  def index
    render json: @people, each_serializer: serializer_method
  end

  private

  def serializer_method
    defined?(@people) ? PeopleSerializer : PersonSerializer
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO it's best to have a specific serializer for each controller action. I built this concern to handle it. (which I add to base controller)

```
module Serializable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

   alias each_serializer serializer

   def serializer
     "#{params[:controller].classify}s::#{params[:action].classify}Serializer".constantize
   end
end
```

That way you can just call

```
render json: @person, serializer:
```

in your controller and it will find the correct serializer.