# How to use multiple Serializers for the same model with ActiveModelSerializer rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

In my controller, i have two methods that render a json, i want to use differents serializer for each method. how can i do it.
i've tried : render json: response ,each_serialiser: SerializerName in every methods by it's doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement multiple different serializers for same model using ActiveModel::Serializers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485404/how-to-implement-multiple-different-serializers-for-same-model-using-activemodel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should create two serializer for each response use one of them and rename the response.

Answer (score 0):

```
render json: @response, serializer: SerializerName
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Did you add "include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON" in the model?

Comment: no i didn't added this line, but when i don't specify which serializer, it works with calling the serializer that have the same name then the model. now i've added a new serializer with a different name and i want to call it for an other action.