# How to exclude some objects from as_json result

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have model `People`. Model has method `hide()`. In a controller a need return list of not hidden models in addiction from some external conditions.

```
# Controller
...
def index
  render json: People.all.as_json
end
```

I thought, that i can place needed contidion to overrided `as_json` method, but i don't know how to exclude hidden models from resulting array.

I override `as_json` method in `People` model:

```
class People
  def as_json(options)
    return false if hidden()
    super(options)
  end

  def hidden?()
    ... # return true or false
  end
  ...
```

Then i call `as_json` for `peoples` array:

```
peoples.aj_json
```

and I get:

```
[
  false,
  false,
  {...}, # model 1
  {...}, # model 2
]
```

But I need get array

```
[
  {...}, # model 1
  {...} # model 2
]
```

Is any way to do this with `as_json`? Or i must create a flag, called `hidden_flag` in a model `People` and filter models when i make request to db?

```
# Controller
...
def index
  peoples = People.where(hidden_flag: false)
  render json: peoples.as_json
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very strange thing you're doing.

You have `as_json` defined on the `People` model (which is bad naming, "people" is plural and model names should be singular), and you override it to return `false`. So, when you call `as_json` on an array of `People` objects, it makes sense that it returns `false` for each element of the array.

If you need to get an empty array in that case, you can use the [clear](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/clear) method to remove all the elements:

`peoples.as_json.clear`

But it looks like you have some serious flaws in your logic if you have to do this.

**After main post edit:**

A blunt approach would be to `return nil` instead of `return false`, and then use the [compact](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-compact) method to get rid of the `nil` values.

But, the better way to do this would be to use something like [Active Model Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers). Here's [a good article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/better-serialization-less-as-json) rationalising its use.

Comment: sorry for my incomplete question. I have method hidden() in my People model. I planned to place condition in my as_json method that exclude hidden peoples from resulting array

Comment: Let's i fix my issue?

Comment: Now it's even more confusing. How about you edit your question to describe what you need to do at a higher level, and I'll take a look again.

Comment: Can i define many output formats with ActiveModel::Serializer? For example:
`render json: @people, :minimal` or `render json: @people, :full`

Comment: Yes, by using several serializers. Take a look at the second answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485404/how-to-implement-multiple-different-serializers-for-same-model-using-activemodel).